# Thread as member variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to have a thread kept as member variable of a class. I want to start the thread inside 'start' method, and stop the thread inside 'stop' method. I also want to be sure that the thread joins, whether or not the 'stop' method is called.

I designed the following code, using `shared_ptr` with custom deleter used to both join the thread and delete the pointer to thread, but I am not 100% sure if it is fully correct.

Please comment on this. Is everything OK here? Or maybe there is a better approach how to do this (e.g. use `unique_ptr` or desing other RAII class)?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void fun() { std::cout << "inside thread\n"; std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); }

class A
{
public:
    A() : pT(nullptr) {}

    void start()
    {
        std::cout << "starting...\n";
        pT.reset(new std::thread(fun), [](auto p) {
            if (p->joinable()) 
            { 
                std::cout << "joining thread\n";
                p->join(); 
            }
            std::cout << "deleting thread\n"; 
            delete p;
       });
    }

    void stop()
    {
        std::cout << "stopping...\n";
        pT.reset();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> pT;
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    a.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is correct:

```
starting...
inside thread
stopping...
joining thread
deleting thread
```

Comment: If there are no specific problems that you are aware of, it would be more appropriate to post this to the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok, I will move it there. I didn't know about Code Review site.

Comment: Just make the thread a member. There's no need for pointers here.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Copiable

Comment: Pete Becker - but if I make it normal thread, not a pointer, then the thread will start automatically when A is constructed. I don't want that. I want the thread to start with 'start' method.

Comment: Joining a thread won't make it stop running. The thread function needs to be designed to receive a "stop" signal so it knows when to return.

Comment: You don't want a `shared_ptr` to a thread. The only reason I can think of to share a thread is if you want to deliberately break the program

Comment: @YotKay: no, it will not automatically start as long as the thread is default constructed. And I'd rather put the cleanup code in A's destructor than using the custom deleter, but that is probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Simpler version: http://ideone.com/Mti9kd

Comment: I know that joining thread doesn't stop the thread. What I want is to just wait for the thread to finish in either of these: (1) calling 'stop' method, (2) destroying object of class A. Solution with smart pointer (doesn't matter if shared_ptr or unique_ptr) allows this.

Answer (score 3):

In my case i like to have the control of what are create and when it is destroyed. So, my proposal is:

You can add the thread pointer as a member of your class and check if it was finish as i show you in this example:

```
class A{

   std::thread *pThread = nullptr; \\ Thread Pointer
   //...
public:
   A();
   ~A();
   void start();
   void stop();
}
```

And used it as:

```
void start()
{
    if(pThread == nullptr) 
    {
       pThread = new thread(fun); //Create the thread and store its reference
    }
}

~A()
{
    if (pThread != nullptr)
    {
        if(pThread->joinable()) \\Wait until the thread has been finished
            pThread->join();
        delete pThread; \\IMPORTANT, release the memory. 
    }
}
```

In this sample i use the thread to synchronized the destruction of Class, it will not be destroyed until the thread has been finished.

**Note**:  If you want to use a method of some class as the function which runs the thread, you can use `std::bind`.

> Also you can use smart pointer as `unique_ptr` instead of `std::thread`, as i made in this sample. In this case the memory will be release  when the class get to be destroyed, so be sure the thread is finished before delete this pointer o leave the context (Class).

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to avoid. Have you heard of 'rule of zero'? The rule says: "Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership (which follows from the Single Responsibility Principle). Other classes should not have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators." Although this is not about ownership, the principle is the same. We should not implement destructors on our own, but we should rely on other classes to perform some tasks for us (like shared_ptr or unique_ptr).

Comment: Ok, in the case you dont want use dynamic memory, use `unique_ptr` but be careful of not leave the context where `unique_ptr` is living before the thread has been finished, otherwise you could cause an exception at the moment of release memory (when the context of  `unique_ptr` has been finished) when the thread is still alive.

Comment: Please, if you want to use raw pointers (which i'm too much a fan of), at least use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. Thanks.